# Wordpress: wp_set_object_terms() not work from included php

Tags: wordpress

I use `wp_set_object_terms` to set terms for user custom taxonomy, this function only works from the plugin **main php file**, but **not** from **included php file**.

for example this works *wp-content/plugins/my_lugin/my_plugin.php*:

```
function set_user_term_a()
{
    $user_professions = Array('aaa','bbb');
    wp_set_object_terms(46, $user_professions, 'user_profession', false);
    clean_object_term_cache(46, 'user_profession');
}
add_action('init', 'set_user_term_a');
```

but if function included from another php it not work

*wp-content/plugins/my_lugin/included_file.php*:

```
echo "the file was successfully included"; // ok
function set_user_term_b()
{
    $user_professions = Array('aaa','bbb');
    wp_set_object_terms(46, $user_professions, 'user_profession', false);
    clean_object_term_cache(46, 'user_profession');
}
add_action('init', 'set_user_term_b');
```

*wp-content/plugins/my_lugin/my_plugin.php*:

```
include_once("included_file.php");
```

Any ideas what wrong?

Comment: Just an idea, try `include("included_file.php");` instead of `include_once()`

Comment: Resolved, the problem was because the file was included a line before register custom taxonomy, it should be after.